# R caret / rfe variable selection for factors() AND NAs

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a data set with `NAs` sprinkled generously throughout.

In addition it has columns that need to be `factors()`.

I am using the `rfe()` function from the `caret` package to select variables.

It seems the `functions=` argument in `rfe()` using `lmFuncs` works for the data with NAs but NOT on factor variables, while the `rfFuncs` works for factor variables but NOT NAs.

Any suggestions for dealing with this?

I tried `model.matrix()` but it seems to just cause more problems.

Comment: I'm skeptical the `lmFuncs` will fail with some variables as factors. I could be convinced with a reproducible example, though. The fact that Random Forests do not (by default) accept cases with NAs is simply a well documented "feature" of that algorithm (or at least the R version of it). If you want tree-based models that seamlessly handle NAs, `treebagFuncs` may be a safer bet (but I haven't tested it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of inconsistent behavior on these points between packages, not to mention the extra trickiness when going to more "meta" packages like `caret`, I always find it easier to deal with NAs and factor variables up front, before I do any machine learning.

- For NAs, either omit or impute (median, knn, etc.).
- For factor features, you were on the right track with `model.matrix()`. It will let you generate a series of "dummy" features for the different levels of the factor. The typical usage is something like this:

```
> dat = data.frame(x=factor(rep(1:3, each=5)))
> dat$x
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
Levels: 1 2 3
> model.matrix(~ x - 1, data=dat)
   x1 x2 x3
1   1  0  0
2   1  0  0
3   1  0  0
4   1  0  0
5   1  0  0
6   0  1  0
7   0  1  0
8   0  1  0
9   0  1  0
10  0  1  0
11  0  0  1
12  0  0  1
13  0  0  1
14  0  0  1
15  0  0  1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$x
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Also, just in case you haven't (although it sounds like you have), the `caret` vignettes on CRAN are very nice and touch on some of these points. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html