# R model.matrix setup

Tags: r

I have a data set that I use the `model.matrix()` function on to convert factor variables to dummy variables. My data has 10 columns like this each with 3 levels (2,3,4) and I've been creating dummy variables for each of them separately.

```
xFormData <- function(dataset){
    mm0 <- model.matrix(~ factor(dataset$type) , data=dataset)
    mm1 <- model.matrix(~ factor(dataset$type_last1), data = dataset)
    mm2 <- model.matrix(~ factor(dataset$type_last2), data = dataset)
    mm3 <- model.matrix(~ factor(dataset$type_last3), data = dataset)
    mm4 <- model.matrix(~ factor(dataset$type_last4), data = dataset)
    mm5 <- model.matrix(~ factor(dataset$type_last5), data = dataset)
    mm6 <- model.matrix(~ factor(dataset$type_last6), data = dataset)
    mm7 <- model.matrix(~ factor(dataset$type_last7), data = dataset)
    mm8 <- model.matrix(~ factor(dataset$type_last8), data = dataset)
    mm9 <- model.matrix(~ factor(dataset$type_last9), data = dataset)
    mm10 <- model.matrix(~ factor(dataset$type_last10), data = dataset)

    dataset <- cbind(dataset, mm0, mm1, mm2, mm3, mm4, mm5, mm6, mm7, mm8, mm9, mm10)

dataset
}
```

I'm wondering if this is the wrong procedure as after running a `randomForest` on the data, and plotting the variable importance, it was showing different dummy variable columns individually.  So say columns 61-63 were the 3 dummy variables for column 10, the `randomForest` is seeing column 62 by itself as an important predictor.

I have 2 questions:

1) Is this ok?

2) If not, how can I group the dummy variables so that the rf knows they are together?

Comment: You do not need to create dummy variables: making sure that they are factors (rather than numbers) should suffice.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd This is actually a follow-up to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145874/r-caret-rfe-variable-selection-for-factors-and-nas/9147316#9147316 , where the OP found that his machine learning workflow *does not* work with factor-coded features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is OK, and is what happens behind the scenes anyway if you left the factors as factors. Different levels of a factor *are* different features for most machine learning purposes. Think of a random example like `test outcome ~ school`: Maybe going to school A is very predictive of whether you pass or fail the test, but not school B or school C. Then, the school A feature would be useful, but not the others.

This is covered in one of the `caret` vignette documents: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caretMisc.pdf

Also, the `cars` data set included with `caret` should be a useful example. It contains 2 factors - "manufacturer" and "car type" - that have been dummy-coded into a series of numeric features for machine learning purposes.

```
data(cars, package='caret')
head(cars)
```

Comment: Thanks.  As a follow up I think if you go about it this way you can't use n-1 levels, but must explicitly code each level which is described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560459/all-levels-of-a-factor-in-a-model-matrix-in-r