# Error in rfe.default ... there should be the same number of samples in x and y

Tags: r, r-caret, rfe

It's pretty straight forward, rfe function below throws this error: "Error in rfe.default(predictors, as.vector(outcomes), sizes = c(5), rfeControl = rfeControl(functions = "lmFuncs", : there should be the same number of samples in x and y"

df first column is a Factor w/ 2 levels. The rest of the df columns are numeric. There are no NA values.

I haven't the slightest clue what this error is on about. I have already tried some other solutions to no avail.

```
rfe_linear <- caret::rfe(
  df[ , -1 ],
  df[ , 1 ],
  sizes = c( 5 ),
  rfeControl = rfeControl(
    functions = 'lmFuncs',
    method = 'boot',
    number = 20
  )
)
```

I tried the below, which gives the same error.

```
rfe_linear <- caret::rfe(
  as.matrix( df[ , -1 ] ),
  df[ , 1 ],
  sizes = c( 5 ),
  rfeControl = rfeControl(
    functions = 'lmFuncs',
    method = 'boot',
    number = 20
  )
)
```

Tried the below. Throws this error: "Error: Must use a vector in `[`, not an object of class matrix."

```
rfe_linear <- caret::rfe(
  as.matrix( df[ , -1 ] ),
  as.factor( df[ , 1 ] ),
  sizes = c( 5 ),
  rfeControl = rfeControl(
    functions = 'lmFuncs',
    method = 'boot',
    number = 20
  )
)
```

Also tried the below, throws this error: "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". Call me crazy, but I don't see an $ operator anywhere in my code.

```
rfe_linear <- caret::rfe(
  df[ , -1 ],
  df[[ 1 ]],
  sizes = c( 5 ),
  rfeControl = rfeControl(
    functions = 'lmFuncs',
    method = 'boot',
    number = 20
  )
)
```

I've tried every combination of as.factor(), as.data.frame(), as.matrix(), df[ , 1 ], df[ , -1 ], df[, 2:ncol( df )], and df[, 1:1 ] that one could think of.

So then I tried this:

```
rfe_linear <- caret::rfe(
  df[ , -1 ],
  df$Phenotype,
  sizes = c( 5 ),
  rfeControl = rfeControl(
    functions = 'lmFuncs',
    method = 'boot',
    number = 20
  )
)
```

Which seemed to run for a while, but of course, R wasn't going to let me get away with running rfe() that easily, so at the end of the log it threw yet another error and the rfe_linear object is still not found.

```
+(rfe) fit Resample01 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample01 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample01 
-(rfe) imp Resample01 
+(rfe) fit Resample02 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample02 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample02 
-(rfe) imp Resample02 
+(rfe) fit Resample03 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample03 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample03 
-(rfe) imp Resample03 
+(rfe) fit Resample04 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample04 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample04 
-(rfe) imp Resample04 
+(rfe) fit Resample05 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample05 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample05 
-(rfe) imp Resample05 
+(rfe) fit Resample06 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample06 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample06 
-(rfe) imp Resample06 
+(rfe) fit Resample07 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample07 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample07 
-(rfe) imp Resample07 
+(rfe) fit Resample08 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample08 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample08 
-(rfe) imp Resample08 
+(rfe) fit Resample09 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample09 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample09 
-(rfe) imp Resample09 
+(rfe) fit Resample10 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample10 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample10 
-(rfe) imp Resample10 
+(rfe) fit Resample11 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample11 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample11 
-(rfe) imp Resample11 
+(rfe) fit Resample12 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample12 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample12 
-(rfe) imp Resample12 
+(rfe) fit Resample13 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample13 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample13 
-(rfe) imp Resample13 
+(rfe) fit Resample14 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample14 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample14 
-(rfe) imp Resample14 
+(rfe) fit Resample15 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample15 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample15 
-(rfe) imp Resample15 
+(rfe) fit Resample16 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample16 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample16 
-(rfe) imp Resample16 
+(rfe) fit Resample17 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample17 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample17 
-(rfe) imp Resample17 
+(rfe) fit Resample18 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample18 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample18 
-(rfe) imp Resample18 
+(rfe) fit Resample19 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample19 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample19 
-(rfe) imp Resample19 
+(rfe) fit Resample20 size: 5191 
-(rfe) fit Resample20 size: 5191 
+(rfe) imp Resample20 
-(rfe) imp Resample20 
Error in { : task 1 failed - "replacement has 1 row, data has 0"
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Comment: The documentation suggests `sizes` should be a vector?

Comment: @SimonWoodward thanks for the response. I have tried passing `5` to the `size` argument instead of passing `c(5)` to the `sizes` argument, all the errors seen above are still thrown.

Comment: @SimonWoodward I realized that I only get the error when I pass `lmFuncs` to the `functions` argument. I'm not sure what this indicates though.

Comment: I'm guessing that `lmFuncs` is inappropriate when `y` is a factor. Your code works when `y` is not a factor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145874/r-caret-rfe-variable-selection-for-factors-and-nas

Answer (score 1):

`lmFuncs` doesn't work when `y` is a factor. `rfFuncs` works, for example.

```r
library(caret)
library(randomForest)

df <- data.frame(y=factor(rnorm(100)>0), 
                 x1=rnorm(100), x2=rnorm(100), x3=rnorm(100), x4=rnorm(100), x5=rnorm(100),
                 x6=rnorm(100), x7=rnorm(100), x8=rnorm(100), x9=rnorm(100), x10=rnorm(100))

rfe_linear <- caret::rfe(
    x = df[,-1],
    y = df[,1],
    sizes = 5,
    rfeControl = rfeControl(
        functions = rfFuncs,
        method = 'boot',
        number = 20
    )
)

rfe_linear
#> 
#> Recursive feature selection
#> 
#> Outer resampling method: Bootstrapped (20 reps) 
#> 
#> Resampling performance over subset size:
#> 
#>  Variables Accuracy   Kappa AccuracySD KappaSD Selected
#>          5   0.5398 0.09997    0.08876  0.1514         
#>         10   0.5478 0.10734    0.07928  0.1433        *
#> 
#> The top 5 variables (out of 10):
#>    x8, x2, x4, x10, x9
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>